# How could I make this variable assignment function into a loop?

Tags: swift, for-loop, switch-statement

I've notated where it repeats. A variable goes into the function, and based on parts of its value, it's routed through this function. However, the same thing needs to repeat with different variables, same otherwise... a lot of times.

Is there a slicker way to do this? I couldn't figure it out with a for loop.

```
    case _ where message.addressParts[0] == "GigPerformer" :
        if message.addressParts[1] == "Main"{
            if message.addressParts[2] == "Voice"{
                if message.addressParts[3] == "CurrentSongName"{
                    gpMainVoice.gpSongNumber = "\(message.arguments.first ?? error)"
                    gpMainVoice.gpSongName = "\(message.arguments.last ?? error)"
                }
                if message.addressParts[3] == "CurrentSongPartName"{
                    gpMainVoice.gpCurrentSongPartNumber = "\(message.arguments.first ?? error)"
                    gpMainVoice.gpCurrentSongPartName = "\(message.arguments.last ?? error)"
                }
                if message.addressParts[3] == "SongPartName"{
                        for i in gpMainVoice.gpSongPartNumber.indices {
                            if "\(message.arguments.first ?? error)" == String(i) {
                                gpMainVoice.gpSongPartNumber[i] = "\(message.arguments.first ?? error)"
                                gpMainVoice.gpSongPartName[i] = "\(message.arguments.last ?? error)"
                            break
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

//                Here's where it repeats

```
        if message.addressParts[2] == "Amp"{
            if message.addressParts[3] == "CurrentSongName"{
                gpMainAmp.gpSongNumber = "\(message.arguments.first ?? error)"
                gpMainAmp.gpSongName = "\(message.arguments.last ?? error)"
            }
            if message.addressParts[3] == "CurrentSongPartName"{
                gpMainAmp.gpCurrentSongPartNumber = "\(message.arguments.first ?? error)"
                gpMainAmp.gpCurrentSongPartName = "\(message.arguments.last ?? error)"
            }
            if message.addressParts[3] == "SongPartName"{
                    for i in gpMainAmp.gpSongPartNumber.indices {
                        if "\(message.arguments.first ?? error)" == String(i) {
                            gpMainAmp.gpSongPartNumber[i] = "\(message.arguments.first ?? error)"
                            gpMainAmp.gpSongPartName[i] = "\(message.arguments.last ?? error)"
                        break
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you put the repeated code into a function and call the function instead? Something roughly like this:

```
func song_information(message, gpMainVoice) {
                if message.addressParts[3] == "CurrentSongName"{
                    gpMainVoice.gpSongNumber = "\(message.arguments.first ?? error)"
                    gpMainVoice.gpSongName = "\(message.arguments.last ?? error)"
                }
                if message.addressParts[3] == "CurrentSongPartName"{
                    gpMainVoice.gpCurrentSongPartNumber = "\(message.arguments.first ?? error)"
                    gpMainVoice.gpCurrentSongPartName = "\(message.arguments.last ?? error)"
                }
                if message.addressParts[3] == "SongPartName"{
                        for i in gpMainVoice.gpSongPartNumber.indices {
                            if "\(message.arguments.first ?? error)" == String(i) {
                                gpMainVoice.gpSongPartNumber[i] = "\(message.arguments.first ?? error)"
                                gpMainVoice.gpSongPartName[i] = "\(message.arguments.last ?? error)"
                            break
                        }
                    }
                }
}
```

And then

```
if message.addressParts[2] == "Voice"{
     song_information(message, gpMainVoice)
}
...
if message.addressParts[2] == "Amp"{
     song_information(message, gpMainVoice)
}
```

Comment: Oh you rock ... that did it!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @purple for this quick answer.

```
        func gpInput (message: OSCMessage, instance:inout GpModel) {
        if message.addressParts[3] == "CurrentSongName"{
            instance.gpSongNumber = "\(message.arguments.first ?? error)"
            instance.gpSongName = "\(message.arguments.first ?? error)"
        }
        if message.addressParts[3] == "CurrentSongPartName"{
            instance.gpCurrentSongPartNumber = "\(message.arguments.first ?? error)"
            instance.gpCurrentSongPartName = "\(message.arguments.last ?? error)"
        }
        if message.addressParts[3] == "SongPartName"{
                for i in gpMainVoice.gpSongPartNumber.indices {
                    if "\(message.arguments.first ?? error)" == String(i) {
                        instance.gpSongPartNumber[i] = "\(message.arguments.first ?? error)"
                        instance.gpSongPartName[i] = "\(message.arguments.last ?? error)"
                    break
                }
            }
        }
            
        }
        if message.addressParts[1] == "Main"{
            if message.addressParts[2] == "Voice"{
                gpInput(message: message, instance: &gpMainVoice)
            }
        }
```